# I am writing a string to a file with ANSI encoding. But the special characters are not displayed properly . (like ł given as ? in the generated file)

Tags: java

this is the code for conversion>

```
String fileContent = "Puławska 558/560,02-884 W-wa";

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(fileContent);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().flush();
        response.getWriter().close();
        response.flushBuffer();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

output file has data:

```
Pu?awska 558/560,02-884 W-wa
```

Comment: You'll need to check which encoding you are using

Comment: I want to use ANSI encoding. Can you please suggest the right format for using it

Comment: There is no such thing as "ANSI encoding". Which encoding are you using to write the file? Which encoding are you using to read the file? Are you 100% sure that they are the same? Are you 100% sure that the file isn't altered in between writing and reading it?

Comment: To me it looks like you're not writing to a file, but into the response to some HTTP request. That's not the same. And by the way, why do you flush and close the PrintWriter twice? `response.getWriter().flush();` and `out.flush();` are both flushing the same object.

Comment: yes Its the response to a http request. and it was utf8 encoding but I want to use windows/1252 or ANSI Encoding. if I use that the special characters are not displayed properly

Comment: response.setContentType("application/octet-stream; charset=windows-1252");

                response.setCharacterEncoding("windows-1252"); this is what I have added to encode it

Comment: The character you want isn't *in* Windows-1252. Can I ask what your reason for rejecting UTF-8 is? It's by far the most common, universal way of representing every character in Unicode.